# Kdevelop as a Rails IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kdevelop

I would like to use Kdevelep as a Ruby on Rails IDE as I'm using Linux. How do I set up Kdevelop to enable this?

Comment: what is this?  In literature and in English,  you have a naked this.  There are so many things an IDE can do i'm not sure what you mean.  plus maybe just use Kate or something like gedit and you'll have a pretty good code editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Kdevelop or Kate, although I don't know that there is a big community of support for these editors.  If you are on Linux you are best to check out VIM, it's the 2nd most popular editor for Ruby/Rails (with Textmate being #1).

There is a really good writeup on how to set-up VIM at:

http://blog.adamlowe.com/2009/12/vim-destroys-all-other-rails-editors.html

If you use VIM with all the various tpope and NerdTree plugins you'll pretty much be set.

Comment: So, the link is broken, again. There is a copy of the text over at http://teamco-anthill.blogspot.se/2010/01/vim-destroys-all-other-rails-editors.html

Answer (score 1):

"Alexander Dymo put some work into the experimental Ruby language plugin, finally making it useful for himself and hopefully others who are Ruby on Rails developers."
http://dot.kde.org/2010/03/08/kate-kdevelop-and-okteta-developers-meet-berlin

http://adymo.blogspot.com/2010/03/ruby-language-support-in-kdevelop4.html
repo at: gitorious.org then /~adymo/kdevelop/adymo-kdevplatform